# Call ng-submit after ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to implement a login window. Therefore I got my start-page where i am including the template for the login window:

```
<div id="footer_wrapper" ng-include="template.url"></div>
```

inside this template there is a form calling submitLogin() on submit:

```
<form ng-submit="submitLogin()">
      <label for="email">E-Mail-Adresse</label><br>
      <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="loginEmail">
      <label for="password">Passwort</label><br>
      <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="loginPassword">
      <p>Passwort vergessen?</p>
      <input type="submit" value="Anmelden">
    </form>
```

But the submitLogin() function is not called when I submit the form.

```
$scope.submitLogin = function(){
    console.log("function login");
    // logUserIn($scope.loginEmail, $scope.loginPassword);
  };
```

I think the ng-include is creating another scope. But how can I access this scope to bind a function to?

Comment: Can you share a plunker please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form ng-submit="submitLogin()">
      <label for="email">E-Mail-Adresse</label><br>
      <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="loginEmail">
      <label for="password">Passwort</label><br>
      <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="loginPassword">
      <p>Passwort vergessen?</p>
      <input type="submit" value="Anmelden">
    </form>
```

this code working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2YsNOnfnUoUhlCpNCubh?p=preview), i think you have done other mistake.

Comment: The form is INSIDE the included template

Comment: You are right. The controller referenced in my app.js stateconfig is not getting called. So i created another conroller only for the form. ty